# JdbcTemplate "queryForObject" and "query" is deprecated in Spring. What should it be replaced by?

Tags: java, sql, spring, spring-boot, jdbctemplate

Query for object,

```java
Student student = return jdbcTemplate.queryForObject("select * from student_id = ?", new Object[] { studentId }, studentRowMapper);
```

For query,

```java
List<Student> students = return jdbcTemplate.query("select * from class_room_id = ?", new Object[] { classRoomId }, studentRowMapper);
```

Both `jdbcTemplate.queryForObject` and `jdbcTemplate.query` are deprecated in spring boot 2.4.X above

Comment: The one with a varargs argument instead of the `Object[]`. This is also explained in the `@depracted` documentation. See https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcOperations.html#query-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object:A-org.springframework.jdbc.core.ResultSetExtractor- as well as explained in the upgrade documentation https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/wiki/Upgrading-to-Spring-Framework-5.x#data-access-and-transactions

Answer (score 49, accepted):

As explained in the [javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcOperations.html#query-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object:A-org.springframework.jdbc.core.ResultSetExtractor-) of the class as well as in [the upgrade/migration guide](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/wiki/Upgrading-to-Spring-Framework-5.x#data-access-and-transactions) it explains that you should use the [varargs method](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcOperations.html#queryForObject-java.lang.String-org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapper-java.lang.Object...-).

```
jdbcTemplate.queryForObject("select * from student_id = ?", studentRowMapper, studentId);
```

and

```
List<Student> students = return jdbcTemplate.query("select * from class_room_id = ?", studentRowMapper, classRoomId);
```

Answer (score 18):

You can just change the order of the array Object[ ] and the mapper. This syntax is supported in the current version. So your code would be:

```
Student student = return jdbcTemplate.queryForObject("select * from student_id = ?", 
studentRowMapper, new Object[] { studentId });
```

and

```
List<Student> students = return jdbcTemplate.query("select * from class_room_id = ?", 
studentRowMapper, new Object[] { classRoomId });
```

You can see the doc of this method [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcOperations.html#query-java.lang.String-org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapper-java.lang.Object...-).

Comment: You can simplify this further by removing the `new Object[] { ... }` around the parameter, as it is a varargs parameter.

Comment: The Object[] is deprecated now, developers should go ahead with the varargs approach, see https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcOperations.html#query(java.lang.String,java.lang.Object%5B%5D,org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapper)