# JdbcTemplate “query” is deprecated in Spring. What is the workaround for dynamic paramter's?

Tags: java, jdbctemplate

[JbdcTemplate - PreparedStatements with Dynamic SQL Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38926798/jbdctemplate-preparedstatements-with-dynamic-sql-query)
is exactly what I have done however jdbctemplate.query is depricated and you cannot pass it in an object instead you should use the varargs method.
[JdbcTemplate "queryForObject" and "query" is deprecated in Spring. What should it be replaced by?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65301011/jdbctemplate-queryforobject-and-query-is-deprecated-in-spring-what-should-i)

But in terms of a dynamic query I have unknown number of parameters so what should I do in this case

FYI the code is working it is just deprecated.

```
private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

List<QueryResults> jdbcQuery(QueryParams queryParams) {
    /* base query */
    StringBuilder sqlQuery = new StringBuilder("Select * from table where 1=1 ");
    /* stores the dynamic preparedStatement arguments */
    List<String> queryArgs = new ArrayList<>();

    if(someCondition){
       sqlQuery.append("And column1 = ? ");
       queryArgs.add(queryParams.value1);
    }
    if(someCondition2){
       sqlQuery.append("And column2 = ? ");
       queryArgs.add(queryParams.value2);
    }
    if(someCondition3){
       sqlQuery.append("And column3 = ? ");
        queryArgs.add(queryParams.value3);
    }
    //etc...

    /* this is the part I used from the above stackoverflow question */
    Object[] preparedStatementArgs = new Object[queryArgs.size()];
    for(int i = 0; i < preparedStatementArgs.length; i++){
        preparedStatementArgs[i] = queryArgs.get(i);
    }

    /* Lastly, execute the query */
    return this.jdbcTemplate.query(sqlQuery.toString(),
    preparedStatementArgs, (rs, rowNum) -> {

        QueryResults result = new QueryResults();
        /* store the results of the query... */
    });
}
```

This is how the code is as of now

Comment: Without knowing which method you are using it is hard to tell. But it looks like you should have been using the `query` method that takes a `PreparedStatementCreator` and `PreparedStatementSetter` from the start.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JdbcTemplate "queryForObject" and "query" is deprecated in Spring. What should it be replaced by?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65301011/jdbctemplate-queryforobject-and-query-is-deprecated-in-spring-what-should-i)

Comment: As stated use the `query` method taking a `PreparedStatementCreator` and `PreparedStatementSetter` instead of what you have now.

Comment: @Zoe no it is not what not I need

Comment: It is. As outlined in the answer, the old functions were deprecated in favor of vararg equivalents. That means you need to change the order or the arguments. Varargs support a single array (in addition to any number of arguments, but not in combination; it's either an array or any number of arguments. You can google this separately), and varargs are _always_ last. All you need to do is move the `preparedStatementArgs` to be the last argument instead of the second.

Comment: Just simply change the order and it should work as you expected. ```jdbcTemplate.query( sql, mapperFunction, sqlStatementArgs)```

In your case:
this.jdbcTemplate.query(sqlQuery.toString(),
     (rs, rowNum) -> {

        QueryResults result = new QueryResults();
        /* store the results of the query... */
    }, preparedStatementArgs);